# How to revert some downgraded packages in my Python environment?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, environment

I have a py3 environment. I needed to instal PIL, so I tried `pip install pil`and just write `y` when I was asked for confirmation. Using this py3 env, I noticed that it now has Python 2.7. Checking my terminal, I found out that I downgraded all this packages:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  appnope                                      0.1.0-py37_0 --> 0.1.0-py27hb466136_0
  asn1crypto                                  0.24.0-py37_0 --> 0.24.0-py27_0
  backcall                                     0.1.0-py37_0 --> 0.1.0-py27_0
  certifi                                   2019.3.9-py37_0 --> 2019.3.9-py27_0
  cffi                                1.12.2-py37hb5b8e2f_1 --> 1.12.2-py27hb5b8e2f_1
  chardet                                      3.0.4-py37_1 --> 3.0.4-py27_1
  cryptography                         2.6.1-py37ha12b0ac_0 --> 2.6.1-py27ha12b0ac_0
  cycler                                      0.10.0-py37_0 --> 0.10.0-py27hfc73c78_0
  idna                                           2.8-py37_0 --> 2.8-py27_0
  ipykernel                            5.1.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 4.10.0-py27_0
  ipython                              7.2.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 5.8.0-py27_0
  ipython_genutils                             0.2.0-py37_0 --> 0.2.0-py27h8b9a179_0
  ipywidgets                                   7.4.2-py37_0 --> 7.4.2-py27_0
  jupyter                                      1.0.0-py37_7 --> 1.0.0-py27_7
  jupyter_client                               5.2.4-py37_0 --> 5.2.4-py27_0
  jupyter_console                              6.0.0-py37_0 --> 5.2.0-py27_1
  jupyter_core                                 4.4.0-py37_0 --> 4.4.0-py27_0
  kiwisolver                           1.0.1-py37h0a44026_0 --> 1.0.1-py27h0a44026_0
  lxml                                 4.3.2-py37hef8c89e_0 --> 4.3.2-py27hef8c89e_0
  mistune                              0.8.4-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 0.8.4-py27h1de35cc_0
  mkl_fft                             1.0.10-py37h5e564d8_0 --> 1.0.10-py27h5e564d8_0
  mkl_random                           1.0.2-py37h27c97d8_0 --> 1.0.2-py27h27c97d8_0
  nbformat                                     4.4.0-py37_0 --> 4.4.0-py27hddc86d0_0
  numpy                               1.15.4-py37hacdab7b_0 --> 1.11.3-py27hacdab7b_12
  numpy-base                          1.15.4-py37h6575580_0 --> 1.11.3-py27h6575580_12
  pandas                              0.23.4-py37h6440ff4_0 --> 0.23.4-py27h6440ff4_0
  pandocfilters                                1.4.2-py37_1 --> 1.4.2-py27_1
  patsy                                        0.5.1-py37_0 --> 0.5.1-py27_0
  pexpect                                      4.6.0-py37_0 --> 4.6.0-py27_0
  pickleshare                                  0.7.5-py37_0 --> 0.7.5-py27_0
  prompt_toolkit                               2.0.7-py37_0 --> 1.0.15-py27h4a7b9c2_0
  ptyprocess                                   0.6.0-py37_0 --> 0.6.0-py27_0
  pycparser                                     2.19-py37_0 --> 2.19-py27_0
  pycurl                            7.43.0.2-py37ha12b0ac_0 --> 7.43.0.2-py27ha12b0ac_0
  pygments                                     2.3.1-py37_0 --> 2.3.1-py27_0
  pyopenssl                                   19.0.0-py37_0 --> 19.0.0-py27_0
  pysocks                                      1.6.8-py37_0 --> 1.6.8-py27_0
  python                                   3.7.2-haf84260_0 --> 2.7.15-h8f8e585_6
  pyzmq                               17.1.2-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 17.1.2-py27h1de35cc_0
  qtconsole                                    4.4.3-py37_0 --> 4.4.3-py27_0
  requests                                    2.21.0-py37_0 --> 2.21.0-py27_0
  scikit-learn                        0.20.3-py37h27c97d8_0 --> 0.20.3-py27h27c97d8_0
  seaborn                                      0.9.0-py37_0 --> 0.9.0-py27_0
  send2trash                                   1.5.0-py37_0 --> 1.5.0-py27_0
  six                                         1.12.0-py37_0 --> 1.12.0-py27_0
  statsmodels                          0.9.0-py37h1d22016_0 --> 0.9.0-py27h1d22016_0
  terminado                                    0.8.1-py37_1 --> 0.8.1-py27_1
  testpath                                     0.4.2-py37_0 --> 0.4.2-py27_0
  tornado                              5.1.1-py37h1de35cc_0 --> 5.1.1-py27h1de35cc_0
  traitlets                                    4.3.2-py37_0 --> 4.3.2-py27hcf08151_0
  urllib3                                     1.24.1-py37_0 --> 1.24.1-py27_0
  wcwidth                                      0.1.7-py37_0 --> 0.1.7-py27h817c265_0
  webencodings                                 0.5.1-py37_1 --> 0.5.1-py27_1
  widgetsnbextension                           3.4.2-py37_0 --> 3.4.2-py27_0
```

How can I rever this?  Thanks.

Comment: PIL is ages old, unmaintained and for Python 2 only. Consider using Pillow instead.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I'm learning this the hard way.